# Polymer 2.0 Styling component distributed children from main doc

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am trying to style some distributed children in Polymer 2.0. I can't seem to get it working following the docs.

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom

I could do this in Polymer 1.x using

```
<style is="custom-style">
        paper-tabs ::content .tab-content {
            background:red;
        }
      </style>
```

Here's my Polymer 2.0 setup trying to change the style of paper-tabs .tab-content

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/custom-style.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <custom-style>
          <style>
            paper-tabs .tab-content {
                background:red;
            }
          </style>
        </custom-style>
        <paper-tabs selected="0" scrollable>
            <paper-tab>The first tab</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Tab two</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>The third tab</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Fourth tab</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just change the background color of the tabs, just do:

```
paper-tabs {
    background:red;
}
```

If you want to style the tab content, there are some paper-tab styling's:

```
--paper-tab-content -- Mixin applied to the tab content
--paper-tab-content-unselected -- Mixin applied to the tab content when the tab is not selected
```

Taken from: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-tabs/elements/paper-tab

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In short, it doesn't look possible to style the .tab-content div but you can can get the same results using your method. Thanks!

Comment: @Rhys, please mark this as the answer, if you could!

Comment: Thanks for the help RivG, you did provide an alternative, but what I was after specifically was that it's actually not possible to style .tab-content and seemingly any distributed children via a class.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like its possible to target .tab-content specifically.

To start with, ::content is replaced with ::slotted but that still doesn't work in this example.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#stylinglightdom

You can use the exposed mixin as RivG also mentioned.
--paper-tab-content